# why the results are a link and not an array ? (google search scraping using PHP )

Tags: php, web-scraping, php-curl

I am trying to get the links of the results of a google search using cURL PHP ,but i get a clickable string with the contents of an array.

Thanks

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q=web+scrapping" ;
echo '</br>' ;
$ch = curl_init() ;

curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'
);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all(
    '!<div class="rc"><div class="r"><a href=(.*?) ping=!',
    $result,
    $match
);

var_dump($match);
curl_close($ch);
```

Here is an image of the results :

[image: Here you can find of the result]

**Edit :** I still can't access the array , here is the code source.

---

```
</br>array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(106) "<div class="rc"><div class="r"><a href="https://www.webharvy.com/articles/what-is-web-scraping.html" ping="
    [1]=>
    string(89) "<div class="rc"><div class="r"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping" ping="
    [2]=>
    string(106) "<div class="rc"><div class="r"><a href="https://www.webharvy.com/articles/what-is-web-scraping.html" ping="
.....
  }
  [1]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(61) ""https://www.webharvy.com/articles/what-is-web-scraping.html""
    [1]=>
    string(44) ""https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping""
    ...

  }
}
```

Comment: Your browser is probably detecting a link and automatically creating a live link. Try viewing it in the browser source.

Comment: Result is an array of strings that var_dump() shows as link since every string is an url.

Comment: @aynber *"Your probably is probably detecting..."* - Pretty sure you meant to write *"Your web browser is probably detecting..."*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah, noticed and fixed. Need more caffeine...

Comment: @aynber :) I know the feeling. I'm on my first now. *Happy and safe holidays!*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner And the same to you! :-D

Comment: thanks for the help guys. $match[1] contains the informations.